# Dynamodb restrict access to user data only

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

how do I restrict dynamoddb  user access to its own data owned by them.
I came access [Using IAM Policy Conditions for Fine-Grained Access Control](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/specifying-conditions.html)

```
 "Condition": {
                    "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                        "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
                            "${www.amazon.com:user_id}"
                        ],
                        "dynamodb:Attributes": [
                            "UserId",
                            "GameTitle",
                            "Wins",
                            "Losses",
                            "TopScore",
                            "TopScoreDateTime"
                        ]
                    }
             }
```

problem with above condition is that my partition key is not the userId.
its something else.

here is what my DB looks like like

```
Hash : "Sales" # its just plain text Sales
Range Date     # its date
attributes : Sale : [  # array of maps
        {
         name : abc,
         userId : idabc,
         some-other : stuff
        },
        {
         name : xyz,
         userId : idxyz,
         some-other : stuff
        }
      ]
```

any idea how to restrict access based on sale[x].userId ?
or any better design how to handle this kind of design ?
I use Date range to query 90% of the data.
other option is to use different table for each and every logical table.
like sales,expense,payroll etc but I don't want to create different tables
and it defeats the purpose or NoSQL I guess.
FYI I am using javascript sdk to access dynamodb from browser.

app has 3 different user types

1. customer (access to its own data)
2. merchants (its own data and access to its customer data)
3. admin (access to all the data)

I think for this I have to create 3 different userPools, correct me if I am wrong.

but cant restrict access to own data, if I use partition key as userId
then querying for merchants becomes difficult.

any suggestion on how do I handle this db design?

thanx